# Why my function in componentDidMount is being called rapidly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, api, state

Im making a function in react that get some information from Youtube API which I want it to get called just once when I refresh the page and put that information in a state. But when I use it in componentDidMount, it wont save the information and my state is still empty. here is the code:

````
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { vid: [] };
    this.vidSearch = this.vidSearch.bind(this);
  }
  vidSearch = async () => {
    const youtubeVid = await Youtube.get("/search");
    this.setState({ vid: youtubeVid.data.items });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.vidSearch();
    console.log(this.state.vid);
  }```
````

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that componentDidMount and not other hook is being called? You can add a console.log("This is componentDidMount") at the start of componentDidMount() to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setState` may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so you won't be able to immediately check the state. But it has an optional callback which you can use that is called *after* the process has completed.

```
vidSearch = () => {
  const youtubeVid = await Youtube.get("/search");
  this.setState({ vid: youtubeVid.data.items }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.vid);
  });
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.vidSearch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will
> trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser
> updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will
> be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate
> state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes
> performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the
> initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be
> necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure
> a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or
> position.

In this case I would change my code to this:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        vid: Youtube.get('/search').data.items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vidSearch` is `async` and you are not `await`ing the returned promise in `componentDidMount` before calling `console.log`.

All `async` functions wrap the return value in a promise, even implicit returns.

You can try `this.vidSearch().then(() => console.log(this.state))`.